# Connecting iOS devices to KVM guest

Tags: usb, kvm, qemu, macos, ios

I'm trying to connect an iPad to a MacOS guest via KVM. The MacOS guest runs fine, PCIe passthrough to a K4000 also works. OS is Fedora 31, 5.5.10-200.fc31.x86_64. Libvirt/virsh is 5.6.0, QEMU is qemu-4.1.1-1.fc31. I'm using this fragment to connect:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb'>
  <source>
    <vendor id='0x05ac'/>
    <product id='0x12ab'/>
  </source>
</hostdev>
```

The iPad tries to connect, then it seems to disconnect and then re-connect, but again to the host instead of the guest. Newer iOS devices seem to re-connect after first being plugged in to change USB descriptors. No usbmuxd is installed as the system is headless/no GUI.

I then created a udev rule to automatically attach the device to the guest when plugged in. Now, when the iPad is plugged in, it seems to repeatedly get attached and detached from the guest, freezing it. If left plugged in, both the iPad and the MacOS guest will eventually crash and reboot.

Any way to get the iPad connected to the guest without a PCIe passthrough of one of the USB controllers? As the system doesn't have that many USB ports anyway, and there is only a single PCI (no e) slot left, I still want to try to find a software solution, instead of using a guest-dedicated USB controller.